# Python: Call Method of Instance by another Instance

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

i want to call a method in an Instance by another new Instance like this:

```
class parentClass:
    # Some methods here
    class a:
        def __init__(self, otherclass):
            otherclass.__foo(a);

    class b:
        def __foo(self, firstclass):
            #do something with firstclass

pClass = parentClass();
classB = pClass.b();
classA = pClass.a(classB);
```

But with this code i will get this kind of error:

```
AttributeError: b instance has no attribute '_a__foo'
```

I already tried to add this before method __foo():

```
@classmethod
```

But this still doesn't works.

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest Solution:

Instead of

```
def __foo(self, firstclass):
```

i have to write

```
def foo(self, firstclass):
```

The double _ won't work here.

I will leave this Question & Answere at this place for other people with the same 'problem'.